# Why is SSH quietly refusing public key auth?

Tags: ssh

I have a clean server, freshly generated RSA key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: steve_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I use the right private key or a random one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah. `~/.ssh` on the server needs to be private.

```
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```